# Play framework: chunked response + apply gzip filters

Tags: scala, http, playframework, gzip, playframework-2.2

I'm using Play 2.2 Scala

It seems that when using chunked response, the filters declaration on Global.scala are ignored (thus my response is not GZip encoded)

I'm currently doing this and it seems to work at first

```
 import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  val enumerator = Enumerator.outputStream { outputStream =>
    val finalOutputStream = {
      if ( canGzip ) new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream)
      else outputStream
    }
    CustomSerializer.serialize(call,finalOutputStream)
  }

  val headers = List(
    Some("Content-Type","application/json"),
    if (canGzip) Some(("Content-Encoding","gzip")) else None
  ).flatten

  Ok.chunked(enumerator).withHeaders(headers: _*)
```

I'm not an http expert so I wonder if it will be fine for all clients.

According to [source code doc](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/a2a8910a8b76bc1cb0da06fa24739536ec9d7bf6/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/play/filters/gzip/GzipFilter.scala#L18), I could also apply a Gzip Enumeratee

```
  val finalEnumerator = if ( canGzip ) {
    jsonEnumerator through Gzip.gzip(bufferSize = 8192)
  } else jsonEnumerator
```

Is there any more idiomatic way to GZip a chunked response in play framework (even latest versions?).

I feel like I'm a bit playing with fire here and that I'll miss some implementation details/headers. If there's a proven way to achieve what I want I'd be interested.

Also asked another related question: [Can Apache/nginx gzip server response if it's already chunked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889079/can-apache-nginx-gzip-server-response-if-its-already-chunked)